# When to Use a Callback function?

Tags: c, callback

When do you use a callback function? I know how they work, I have seen them in use and I have used them myself many times.

An example from the C world would be `libcurl` which relies on callbacks for its data retrieval.

An opposing example would be OpenSSL: Where I have used it, I use out parameters:

```
ret = somefunc(&target_value);
if(ret != 0)
    //error case
```

I am wondering when to use which? Is a callback only useful for async stuff? I am currently in the processes of designing my application's API and I am wondering whether to use a callback or just an out parameter. Under the hood it will use libcurl and OpenSSL as the main libraries it builds on and the parameter "returned" is an OpenSSL data type.

I don't see any benefit of a callback over just returning. Is this only useful, if I want to process the data in any way instead of just giving it back? But then I could process the returned data. Where is the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the simplest case, the two approaches are equivalent. But if the callback can be called multiple times to process data as it arrives, then the callback approach provides greater flexibility, and this flexibility is not limited to async use cases.

libcurl is a good example: it provides an API that allows specifying a callback for all newly arrived data. The alternative, as you present it, would be to just *return the data*. But return it — how? If the data is collected into a memory buffer, the buffer might end up very large, and the caller might have only wanted to save it to a file, like a downloader. If the data is saved to a file whose name is returned to the caller, it might incur unnecessary IO if the caller in fact only wanted to store it in memory, like a web browser showing an image. Either approach is suboptimal if the caller wanted to process data as it streams, say to calculate a checksum, and didn't need to store it at all.

The callback approach allows the caller to decide how the individual chunks of data will be processed or assembled into a larger whole.

Answer (score 4):

Callbacks are useful for asynchronous notification.  When you register a callback with some API, you are expecting that callback to be run when some event occurs.  Along the same vein, you can use them as an intermediate step in a data processing pipeline (similar to an 'insert' if you're familiar with the audio/recording industry).

So, to summarise, these are the two main paradigms that I have encountered and/or implemented callback schemes for:

1. I will tell you when data arrives or some event occurs - you use it as you see fit.
2. I will give you the chance to modify some data before I deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

If the value can be returned immediately then yes, there is no need for a callback.  As you surmised, callbacks are useful in situations wherein a value *cannot* be returned immediately for whatever reason (perhaps it is just a long running operation which is better performed asynchronously).

Answer (score 0):

My take on this: I see it as which module has to know about which one? Let's call them Data-User and IO.
Assume you have some IO, where data comes in. The IO-Module might not even know who is interested in the data. The Data-User however knows exactly which data it needs. So the IO should provide a function like subscribe_to_incoming_data(func) and the Data-User module will subscribe to the specific data the IO-Module has. The alternative would be to change code in the IO-Module to call the Data-User. But with existing libs you definitely don't want to touch existing code that someone else has provided to you.